# What is maximum weightage allowed in solr search?

Tags: solr, lucene

I there any limit for weightage that we can allow in SOLR search query.

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. All scores are floating point numbers, so as long as you're within the range of expressible floats, you should be ok. However, there are a few limits in relation to encoding norms (boosts / normalized field length) stored in the index format itself. This has usually been limited to a single byte of information. This shouldn't affect boosts in queries as far as I know.